# Python Django Admin site Custom Query Set

Tags: python, django

**Background**

I have a Usergroup model

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

1. I want to add this on Django’s admin site so that a admin can create User groups and also assign Users to Usergroups
2. **A user should only be allowed to be in one User group**
3. A user also doesn’t have to be in a group
4. Dont want a usergroup field on my User Model

Below is what I have for my  admin site at the moment.

```
class UserGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    search_fields = ('name',)

    filter_horizontal = ('users',)

admin.site.register(UserGroup, UserGroupAdmin)
```

It looks like this when Creating a group adding users ect.

[image]

My thought was to change the query set to only show Users who are not in a Group and the users who are currently in the group

Which means.

1. Under Available Users You will only be allowed to Add / see users who are not yet in a group.
2. **Under Chosen User View Users already in this current Group.**

**Question**

Im not sure how to approach changing the Query set.

The below Works great to only show Users not in a group.

But now **I cant see Users already in the "Current" group.**

Which means I cant remove users from a group only add them.

```
class UserGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('users',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'users':
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(usergroup__isnull=True)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(UserGroup, UserGroupAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

This was my final solution thanks to  willeM_ Van Onsem

```
class UserGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('users',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'users':
            object_id = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('object_id')
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(
                Q(usergroup=None) | Q(usergroup=object_id)
            )
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(UserGroup, UserGroupAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly alter the approach with:

```
from django.db.models import Q


class UserGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('users',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'users':
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(
                Q(usergroup=None)
                | Q(usergroup=self.request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('object_id'))
            )
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)


admin.site.register(UserGroup, UserGroupAdmin)
```

But I agree it is ugly, it is partly because the `ModelAdmin` does *not* spawn a separate view object per request, and thus has not that much of a "context" for each request.

Comment: Thanks alot pointed me in the right direction. I posted my Final version which works fine if you would like to have a look :)